# from Keynote to LaTeX help to build a visual slide

Tags: slideshow

Anyone any ideas how could I craft such slide? Im writing a presentation and I want to transition some slides from Keynote to LaTeX. How could I build such big letters inside a visual spectrum ? Using pgf-spectra or pstricks?

The left icons are vectorial images. The right is just text.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: An attempt to show a basic MWE could help this question find its way into the interest of people who can help in hours rather than guessing what the author struggles with the most.

Comment: Im crafting something using pgf-spectra. if I get to something useful will post here